# Prove that $\lim_{x \to ∞}(\frac{a_nx^n + ... + a_0}{b_mx^m + ... + b_0})$ exists if and only if $ m ≥ n.$

Tags: real-analysis, limits

Prove that $$\lim_{x \to ∞}\left(\frac{a_nx^n + ... + a_0}{b_mx^m + ... + b_0}\right)$$ with $a_n \neq 0$ and $b_m \neq 0$ exists if and only if $m \ge n$.

I thought about proving by contradiction assuming $m \lt n$ but I ended up doing a lot of case work so I was wondering if there is a more elegant solution that I'm not thinking of.

Comment: Divide through by $x^m$, then analyze the resulting expression.

Comment: Or to make the analysis a bit easier one can write it as $$x^{n-m} \frac{a_n+ a_{n-1} x^{-1}+\dots a_0 x^{-n}}{b_m+b_{m-1}x^{-1}+\dots +b_0 x^{-m}}.$$

Comment: Are you supposed to use epsilon-delta definition?

Comment: I thought I was supposed to use epsilon-delta, which is where my confusion came from. It turns out I don't, so dividing by $x^m$ helped me solve it. Thanks!

Comment: Despite what some authors say, I would caution learners of calculus that $\lim f(x)=\infty$ is *not* an example of a limit existing; it is the limit failing to exist in a specific way. So in my view, the limit should exist if and only if $m=n$, not $m\ge n$. (If $m>n$, the limit is written "$=\infty$" but does not exist.)

Comment: @GregMartin If m>n then the limit is zero, not "infinity", so it does exist. Also, the reason some authors say the limit exist when it is infinity is often because they're considering the extended reals. For example, there are sets of infinite Lebesgue measure, so if you have a sequence of measurable sets tending to such a set E, their measure would tend to infinity, and then you would have to say the limit of the sequence of measures does not exist whilst the measure of E exist and is infinite, and it can be confusing.

Comment: @Divide1918 Sorry about confusing $m$ and $n$. I'm speaking from the standpoint of somebody who is learning calculus (which is the audience of this post). At that point, talking about the extended reals and measurable sets is premature and counterproductive to students' learning.

Comment: @GregMartin Measurable sets is but an example to illustrate the contexts in which one might encounter infinite limits. However, discussion of extended reals can also illustrate the difference between divergence by blowing up to infinity and other types divergences like infinite oscillation. The theorems in basic calculus can be stated by considering infinity as a valid limit. If you give someone who don't know calculus but is aware of the idea of infinity the graph of tan(x) and ask them "what's tan(x) at π/2“, they would likely answer "infinity".

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure if this makes sense, but as x approaches $\infty$, only the $\frac{a_{n}x^{n}}{b_{m}x^{m}}$ part will be relevant. If $m<n$, $\frac{a_{n}x^{n}}{b_{m}x^{m}}$ will approach $\pm\infty$ because the numerator is greater than the denominator, so it doesn't exist. When $m>n$, the limit will approach zero because the denominator is larger than the numerator. Finally, when $m=n$, the limit will just equal $\frac{a_{n}}{b_{m}}$, which is defined.

Comment: It does make sense and while not a rigorous proof (it can be turned into one) this is usually how one gets the right answer quickly in these problems.

Answer (score 0):

$$\lim_{x \to \infty} \frac{\sum\limits_{k=1}^{n}a_k}{\sum\limits_{k=1}^{m}b_k}=\lim_{x \to \infty} \frac{a_n\prod\limits_{k=1}^{n}(x-\alpha_k)}{b_m\prod\limits_{k=1}^{m}(x-\beta_k)}$$

This is simply by polynomial decomposition. $\alpha_k$ and $\beta_k$ are the zeros of the two polynomials.

Now we can reduce the number of factors in the expression because
$$\lim_{x \to \infty} \frac{x-p}{x-q}=\lim_{x \to \infty} \frac{1-\frac{p}{x}}{1-\frac{q}{x}}=1 $$

regardless of the value of $p$ and $q$

For this reason, you are left with

$$\lim_{x \to \infty} \frac{a_n\prod\limits_{k=1}^{n-m}(x-\alpha'_k)}{b_m}=+\infty, n>m$$

$$\lim_{x \to \infty} \frac{a_n}{b_m\prod\limits_{k=1}^{m-n}(x-\beta'_k)}=0, m>n$$

$$\lim_{x \to \infty} \frac{a_n}{b_n}=\frac{a_n}{b_n}, m=n$$

Notice that the choice of $\alpha$ and $\beta$ while canceling is irrelevant. (This is why we used ' to specify that these are some initial zeros.) You can order them and group them two by two or take whatever other way of selection.

The conclusion follows.